# strftime/strtotime syntax

Tags: php, json, syntax, strtotime, strftime

I have this working piece of code (PHP). The problem I encountered is with the strftime('%e %B',strtotime($time)); part (is at the end of the block). It returns nothing.. What am I doing wrong? Maybe a syntax error?

```
<?php
function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params)
{
    $r = array();
    ksort($params);
    foreach($params as $key=>$value){
        $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
    }

    return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r)); //return complete base string
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth)
{
    $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
    $values = array();
    foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
        $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";

    $r .= implode(', ', $values);
    return $r;
}

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$oauth_access_token = "XXXXXX";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "XXXXXX";
$consumer_key = "XXXXXX";
$consumer_secret = "XXXXXX";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce' => time(),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'count' => 6,   
    'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;


$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?count=6',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$twitter_data = json_decode($json);

echo "
            <ul style='color:#6E6E6E'>";

foreach ($twitter_data as $tweet)
{
    if (!empty($tweet)) {
        $text = $tweet->text;
    }
    if (!empty($tweet)) {
        $id = $tweet->id;
    }
    if (!empty($tweet)) {
        $time = $tweet->created_at;
    }
    if (!empty($tweet)) {
        $username = $tweet->user->name;
    }
    echo '<li>';
    echo $text . "<br><a href=\"http://twitter.com/";
    echo $username ;
    echo '/status/';
    echo $id ;
    echo '"><small>';
    strftime('%e %B',strtotime($time));
    ' </small></a> - <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=';
    echo $id;
    echo '"><small>rispondi</small></a> - <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id=';
    echo $id;
    echo '"><small>retweet</small></a> - <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/favorite?tweet_id=';
    echo $id;
    echo '"><small>preferito</small></a></li>';
}

echo '
            </ul>';

?>
```

Comment: Could you try and post a more minimal example next time? Quite a bit easier to debug if there's not all that other stuff around. Just check if it still fails without all the twitter stuff, and post 1 maybe 2 lines you can verify also don't work as expected?

Comment: Well, the twitter part is needed because I need to be sure that the function works on the time retrieved by twitter JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it just me or are you just missing an `echo`? Or are you intending to concatenate with `.`?

```
...
echo $id ;
echo '"><small>'; 
strftime('%e %B',strtotime($time)); ' </small></a> - <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='; 
echo $id;
...
```

Should be...

```
...
echo $id ;
echo '"><small>'; 
echo strftime('%e %B',strtotime($time));
echo ' </small></a> - <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to='; 
echo $id; 
...
```

Comment: Oh God.. I should rest. ahah Thank you! :)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno Second pair of eyes usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Warning
>
> Windows only:
>
> The %e modifier is not supported in the Windows implementation of this function. To achieve this value, the %#d modifier can be used instead. The example below illustrates how to write a cross platform compatible function.
>
> The %z and %Z modifiers both return the time zone name instead of the offset or abbreviation.

**Reference:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: Since you didn't mention that in your post, I had no way of knowing :)

Comment: You're right. :)
Anyway, I think it's not a function's problem.. more a syntax one.. Because on the same VPS I use the function in the same way (for other stuff) and it works

Comment: you're not checking if `$date` is set, can you re-check if it's set and has real data ?

Comment: I will leave my answer here because it may be of help to other users.